# XCode 14.3 doesn't list iOS devices with 16.4

Tags: ios, flutter, macos-ventura, xcode-command-line-tools, xcode14.3

I'm about to upgrade to Xcode 14.3 and installed that version in addition to version 14.2, where i'm switching between those 2 versions by using the command
`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_14.X.app`.

When version 14.2 is active i can see the connected iOS device (iOS version 16.4.1) with
`flutter devices` or `xcrun xcdevice list`.

As soon as i switch to version 14.3 that device is not listed anymore and therefore i also cannot target it for a deployment in my IDE IntelliJ (since there is a similar command used to populate the device selector box).
Interesting is that i see that iOS device when opening Xcode 14.3 and i even can deploy my Flutter app to that device within Xcode.
I tested with most recent stable Flutter versions (3.7.11 and 3.7.12) which contain fixes for using Xcode 14.3.

Devices with older iOS versions (i.e. 15.7.x) are listed without any problems on the command line when using Xcode 14.3.

Can someone tell me how i can get that device listed and then use it as a deployment target?

**UPDATE 3**: When calling `xcrun xctrace list devices` the iPhone with iOS 16.4.1 is correctly listed, so probably there is a problem with xcdevice.
I've also created tickets at Apple dev forums, and to me it's an evidence of incapacity that after more than 3 weeks no one there seems to care nor at least respond to this issue, where i'm definitely not the only one who encounters this problem.

**UPDATE 2**: Since everything works fine within Xcode 14.3 i tend to say that the problem arises between Command Line Tools and iOS 16.4.x (and perhaps also MacOS Ventura).

**UPDATE**: After further tests i can say that the problem doesn't involve Flutter imo. I get the following (quite often seen) error when calling `/usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcdevice list --timeout 2` with XCode 14.3 enabled:

```
xcdevice[1473:15359] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
```

With Xcode 14.2 this error doesn't show up and the iOS device with iOS Version 16.4.1 is listed.
I'm using MacOS Ventura 13.3.1.

In my opinion there is some misbehaviour between that MacOS version, Xcode 14.3 and devices with iOS version 16.4.x.

Comment: when you go on iOs folder on project navigator and right click on that and click open in xcode which version of xcode opened?

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar The one that has been applied with `xcode-select`

Comment: can you open in xcode without command and work with xcode directly?

Comment: As mentioned: yes, that works, but it's not the way how i intend to work. I also cannot deploy from within my IDE anymore when XCode 14.3 is active. Therefore i need to find a way to solve this issue.

Comment: It's so weird, may be this link help you: https://fredriccliver.medium.com/how-to-choose-xcode-version-for-flutter-build-3cade52917b9

Comment: Not really, since i don't have a problem in switching XCode versions ;-)

Comment: I am using VS IOS 16.4 with Xcode 14.3 if you lower  Xcode version to a previous version (I used 13.4.1) and restart your IDE compile once( and it fails) and then revert back to the latest version it might work. This worked for me.

Comment: @riee923 As mentioned this even works with going down to Xcode version 14.2, but as soon as i'm going back to 14.3 (or 15 beta) the device isn't listed anymore. Btw. this problem is project independent.

Comment: @valley I had exactly the same issue and got it working by going through the steps I mentioned. Hope a new version of compatible Xcode comes out soon. All the best!