# Flutter no longer works on mac os if project is synced with icloud

Tags: flutter

Update: Still have issues but I know why. Android works.  Xcode does not.  Issues if the project is in a folder synced to iCloud.  I create any project in a directory synced to iCloud I get the below error.  If I create a project outside of a dir not synced to iCloud then works. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18505

If I move the project outside of the directory it works. I still want to know why this happens and how to resolve.

Flutter hangs on Flutter run.  I created a new project.  Before it was working and though was my existing project but even on a new project it does not work.

Stuck here ...

```
flutter run 
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
```

I am on an m1 mac 13.5.2 wth Xcode 14.3.1
Flutter version is

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.13.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 367f9ea16b (2 days ago) • 2023-09-12 23:27:53 -0500
Engine • revision 9064459a8b
Tools • Dart 3.1.2 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

Flutter Doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.4, on macOS 13.5.2 22G91 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.1.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.3.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.3.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.1.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

I am out of options.  Flutter please help!

Below is output of run -v upto the last line where it hangs.

```
 2023-09-15 04:34:17.800 xcdevice[16472:140956] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled
                    set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
```

Comment: Can you make sure that https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos , you have downloaded Apple Silicon one and can you give more info about if you have done any changes before, when it was working

Answer (score 0):

> there is some misbehaviour between that MacOS version, Xcode 14.3 and devices with iOS version 16.4.x.

> I ended up using 14.2 command line tools, which works fine. —  mattlo 3 months ago

**The same problem:**

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/729395

[XCode 14.3 doesn't list iOS devices with 16.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76166089/xcode-14-3-doesnt-list-ios-devices-with-16-4)

Comment: See my update.  I came across a thread about iCloud syncing